# one click separate windows in javascript

Tags: javascript, click

my main intention is to open windows separately not tabs in single click on all browsers so below is the code which work successfully with single click and opens single window, i need to open multiple window with same code. Please modify it to open multiple tabs.

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
<!--
function popup(mylink, windowname)
{
if (! window.focus)return true;
var href;
if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
   href=mylink;
else
   href=mylink.href;
window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes');
return false;
}
//-->

</SCRIPT>

<A HREF="http://www.google.com" 
   onClick="return popup(this, 'notes')">my popup</A>
```

Any method will be appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: I dont think theres any way of doing this.  If you control the windows you are opening you could embed code in them and get the new windows to open up the extra tabs.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change window name for each new window you open here is a sample

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
for(var i=1;i<5;i++){
    window.open("http://www.google.com",i+"MyNewWindows","height=200,width=200");
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hes looking for 'x' tabs inside the new window not 'x' windows

Answer (score 0):

you must use different name for different window.

This can work in your case

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
var c = 0;
  function popup(mylink, windowname) {
      c++;
    if (!window.focus) return true;
    var href;
    if (typeof (mylink) == 'string')
        href = mylink;
    else
        href = mylink.href;
    window.open(href, windowname+c, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes');
    return false;
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple.

**HTML**

```
 <input type="button" value="Open Windows" onclick="openWin()">
```

**JS**

```
for (var i =0; i<2; i++){
window.open("http://www.google.com/");
}
```

}

You should also know that window.open is sometimes blocked by popup blockers and/or ad-filters.So you need to change permission to allow the popup blocker.

And additional information : This approach also places a dependency on JavaScript being enabled. Not typically a good idea, but sometimes necessary.